# jQuery Mobile: Dialog select does not update on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am currently using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 on my page. Here is the specific scenario I am having trouble with.

I have a select list using the select menu widget. It is hidden on the page at first (in a separate jQuery mobile page within the same HTML file).

```
<select name="title-dropdown" id="title-dropdown" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    <option value="7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="10">Option 10</option>
    <option value="11">Option 11</option>
    <option value="12">Option 12</option>
    <option value="13">Option 13</option>
    <option value="14">Option 14</option>
    <option value="15">Option 15</option>
    <option value="16">Option 16</option>
    <option value="17">Option 17</option>
    <option value="18">Option 18</option>
    <option value="19">Option 19</option>
    <option value="20">Option 20</option>
    <option value="21">Option 21</option>
    <option value="22">Option 22</option>
</select>
```

When the page is displayed, I use jQuery to update the value.

```
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#edit-page", function() {
    $('#title-dropdown').val('12').selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

Now when I click on the dropdown, it opens up a dialog box because it is longer than the screen (which is expected behavior). However, when I click on one of the options, the  is not updated. It will still say "Option 12" no matter what other option I click on.

If I don't set the value using jQuery the dropdown works perfectly fine. If I reduce the number of options so it doesn't need to use a dialog, it works fine. It is only when I update the value via jQuery when it uses a long list that it breaks.

Any ideas as to why the select dialog no longer works in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the dialog of select options is dismissed, the main page show event is triggered again. So no matter what you select, it is always overwritten.

You could use the **[pagecontainer widget's show](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show)** event instead and only set the select value if the previous page is not the dialog:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.toPage.prop("id") == "edit-page" && ui.prevPage.prop("id") != "title-dropdown-dialog" ){
        $('#title-dropdown').val('12').selectmenu("refresh");
    }
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/nwuq02d3/)**

Comment: Perfect! I had no idea the pageshow events were fired when dialogs were closed. Thanks.

Comment: @BrandonS, dialogs are actually another page, so pageshow fires for the dialog being shown and then when you navigate back to the main page it is also being "shown" again.